# foreignkey django

Tags: python, django, django-models

how to choice multiple instances of a foreignkey for example

```
class Mobile(models.Model):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    imei = models.ForeignKey(Imei,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Imei(models.Model):
    imei = models.CharField(max_length=13,unique=True)
```

each mobile have different `Imei` in `Mobile` if mobile =`samsung A51` and `quantity = 10` then we have 10 unique  `imei`

i want to know how to let the user the select 10 imei's (with barcode reader) in the same form ?

i appreciate your helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need here is [ManyToMany relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships). Your `Mobile` model will look like.

```
class Mobile(models.Model):
    mobile = models.CharField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField(
    imei = models.ManyToManyField(Imei)
```

EDITED: Since there are unique imei for each `Mobile`, you have 2 options to achieve this

1. Either implement the unique validation at the time of adding an object to the `ManyToManyField`. (I think this will simplify your relationships)
2. If you really want to have this logic in db, create a middle table to save the relationship. You have your `Mobile` table and `Imei` table. Create another table to store the relationship of both, let's say `MobielImei` with following fields

```
class MobileImei(models.Model):
    mobile = models.ForeignKey(Mobile)
    imei = models.ForeignKey(Imei)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("mobile", "imei")
```

This `unique_together` will ensure, that for every mobile there's a unique `imei` and single `imei` is also associated to a unique `mobile.`